# MYSQL FULLTEXT search not working properly

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

If i am search a term 'will walk', then the result will show all the entries similar with the search term.
For example:

```
Search Term: will walk
Records: 
1. It will walk.
2. tomorrow rain will walk.
3. it should walk
4. walk on
5. tomorrow bus will walk.
Result: 1, 2, 5
```

I will try with the query `SELECT * FROM user WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('+will +walk' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` but i get all the entries(1,2,3,4,5) as result.

Comment: It works correctly, because [**'will'** is stopword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and is ignored in [boolean full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: @Rimas, yes, you are correct. Its working fine. Thank you :) .

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'LIKE' operator to search for a part of a phrase from a phrase

Like so:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%will walk%'
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Yes it will work but i need a solution to work with full text search.

Answer (score 0):

For full text search add `%` as separator for every words. Your query should be looks like this :

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%will%walk%'
```

This would return all record that has words *will* and *walk* in column `name`. Even if it was `will be walk`.

Comment: I have used query like: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('%will%walk%' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`. But it will return all the records(mentioned in the question).

Comment: @user2349080 I missunderstood your question. You want to return all records or just 1, 2, 5?